# authentication in django with extending one-to-one relationship

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-authentication, django-login

i've made authentication system that user can login based on User Models. In User Models, it's extended with one-to-one relationship. When i insert login with username and password, it works. But when i insert login with username, password, and hak_akses. It doesn't work properly. I want authentication can work with insert username, password, and hak_akses. But, i still don't know how to do it

This is my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^login/', views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^auth/$', views.auth_view, name="auth"),
```

This is my models

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # This line is required. Links UserProfile to a User model instance.
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    # The additional attributes we wish to include.
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        ('admin','Admin'),
        ('user','User'),
        )
    hak_akses = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices = CATEGORY_CHOICES)

    # Override the __unicode__() method to return out something meaningful!
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

This is my views

```
def login(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response('login.html', c)

def auth_view(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username', '')
    password = request.POST.get('password', '')
    akses = User.objects.select_related().all()
    hak_akses = request.POST.get('hak_akses', '')
    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password, hak_akses=hak_akses)

    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/simofa/')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/simofa/login')
```

This is my login template:

```
<form class="form-login" method="post" action="/simofa/auth/" name="login">{% csrf_token %}
                <h2 class="form-login-heading">SISTEM MANAJEMEN OTENTIKASI FASILKOM UI</h2>
                <div class="login-wrap">
                    <input name="username" id="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="User ID" autofocus>
                    <br>
                    <input name="password" id="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                <br>
                <select name="hak_akses">
                  <option name="hak_akses" value="admin">Admin</option>
                  <option name="hak_akses" value="user">User</option>
                </select>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-theme btn-block"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                </div>      
              </form>
```

Comment: Have you looked at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/

Comment: yes i have. but i still not undestand about customizing authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using django's authentication function (i.e. `from django.contrib.auth import authenticate`), then you should check how authentication function has been implemented. check here from django's [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/0f7f5bc9e7a94ab91c2b3db29ef7cf000eff593f/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py#L62). Here in line 72:

```
 ....

    try:
        user = backend.authenticate(**credentials)
    except PermissionDenied:

  ....
```

and backend.authenticate is implemented like this:

```
def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        if username is None:
            username = kwargs.get(UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD)
        try:
            user = UserModel._default_manager.get_by_natural_key(username)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            # Run the default password hasher once to reduce the timing
            # difference between an existing and a non-existing user (#20760).
            UserModel().set_password(password)
```

As you can see, it takes 2 arguments, username and password or if username is none, then it takes username from kwargs. So if you want to make authentication using your own field like `hak_akses`, you need to write your own authentication backend like this [django test custom authentication backend](https://github.com/django/django/blob/731f313d604a6cc141f36d8a1ba9a75790c70154/tests/test_client_regress/auth_backends.py).

Easier solution, make a function which takes `hak_akses` as kwargs and do authentication. For example:

```
def custom_authenticate(self, username=None, password=None, hak_akses=None ):
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
           user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)
           if user_profile.hak_akses == hak_akses
              return user_profile
    return None
```

Comment: thanks for your input. But, i've an error like this. 

"The view simofa.views.custom_authenticate didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead."

Comment: hey thank you very much. i've modified your input. after username and password authenticated. i must check hak_akses with create a new condition like this.

Comment: You are welcome. BTW, what I have written is a function which is not a view but a normal function, and usage is like this: c_`user = custom_authentication(username='hello', password='world', hak_akses='asd')`  and `c_user` will be either 'UserProfile' object or `None`

Answer (score 0):

i've solved my problems. After i check the authentication like username and password. I must create condition to check the hak_akses variable like this.

```
def auth_view(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username', '')
    password = request.POST.get('password', '')
    # hak_akses = request.POST.get('hak_akses', '')
    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)
        auth.login(request, user)
        if user_profile.hak_akses == hak_akses:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/simofa/')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/simofa/login')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/simofa/login')
```

Thanks you very much @ruddra